# C# Automatic numbering Datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview, bindingsource

Is it possible in datagridview with a bindingsource when adding a new row it's copy the last cell name and put a number to it? Copy the name is not a problem but the number after the name i can't get solved. The result i'm looking for is when you press the add button, you get: Sheet 1, Sheet 2, Sheet 3 etc (See image how it should look) with the code i have now you get: Sheet 1, Sheet 11, Sheet 111 etc.

Thanks!

[image]

```
        private void newSheet_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string newItemName;
        string newItemNumber;
        string newItemDrawnBy; 

        if (bindingSource1.Count > 0)
        {
            bindingSource1.MoveLast();
            SheetResource lastItem = bindingSource1.Current as SheetResource;

            newItemName = lastItem.Name + " " + 1; 
            newItemNumber = lastItem.Number;
            newItemDrawnBy = lastItem.Drawn;
        }
        else
        {        
            newItemName = "Sheet";
            newItemNumber = "A-00";
            newItemDrawnBy = "Author";
        }

        SheetResource newItem = new SheetResource();
        newItem.Name = newItemName;
        newItem.Number = newItemNumber;
        newItem.Drawn = newItemDrawnBy;

        bindingSource1.Add(newItem);
    }
```

Comment: have you tried to get gridview.items.count and add it to your new row?

Comment: Well, your code is the following `lastItem.Name + " " + 1` - if you think about (or had a look while debugging) - you would know/see that `lastItem.Name` is the Value `Sheet 3` - so what you are getting is `"Sheet 3" + " " + 1` which result int "Sheet 3 1" since you are only combining strings and not doing any numeric operation - what you want is get the number out of your string and do a numeric operation on it to get the next higher number